# What battery do I need for a Canon EOS 500?

Tags: canon, battery

I got a old Canon EOS 500 (analogic) of my girlfriend, but I need to buy batteries, but do not know what the correct battery for her, found a manual on the internet and said CR123A or DL123A, but found no amperage specification (3v, 3.7, 4v ).

I sent an email to the canon but got no answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually have all the information you need. CR123A is what you need to buy. They happen to be 3V, and up to 1500mAh, lithium chemistry but not rechargeable.

You should be able to find them in a camera shop, a chemist, or even a large supermarket, but it's easy and cheap to order them online.

There is a rechargeable in the same shape, with a slightly higher voltage that might still work, but getting a charger for it isn't easy, so the batteries are rare as well.  In an analogue camera they last ages (many, many rolls of film when I used to use a compact that took them).

Comment: Thanks, I thought I'd better ask before than damage it the gift I received. thx

Comment: Just as a note they are typically much cheaper on line.  I just picked up a box of 12 CR123 batteries on amazon for less than 2 at the grocery.

Comment: @Matthew the OP may never get through a dozen, but it is worth nothing as you say (I knew this for coin cells but the last time I bought a CR123 was for a wireless *serial* mouse and Amazon was an upstart). In editing in the cost online I found a typo so double thanks.

Comment: @ChrisH Considering that the EOS film cameras all had built in film winders/rewinders one goes through the batteries much faster than a 35mm camera with manual film advance/rewind.

Comment: @MichaelClark the compact I had used a motor winder too. Probably a less powerful one though.

Comment: "Ages"? No, non-rechargeable lithiums in 1990s style film SLRs were often a significant cost factor...

Comment: @rackandboneman they weren't cheap (I think they've got cheaper and not just in real terms) but I found them to last many rolls of film while costing a similar amount or a bit less. This was in a 35mm compact so it also powered the only available flash. I'd expect an SLR to last longer as you'd be less likely to use an external flash.

Answer (score 2):

CR123 is a Lithium battery with a nominal value of 3.7 volts.  If you were to measure the voltage it would be between 3 and 4.  Being a battery the voltage will change as the battery is used.  (It can even change based on temperature, age and many other factors.)

There are tons of different names and numbers for the same battery… DL123a, CR123, EL123, K123 are just some examples.

http://www.batteriesdirect.com/product/details/photo-lithium-batteries/energizer/cr123
https://www.batteryjunction.com/olight-16340-650mah.html

Comment: Thx, Matthew for the response.

Comment: The CR123A has a nominal voltage of just 3 volts not 3.7 volts. It is listed right in the specs.

Comment: Depends on the chemistry of the battery. The spec voltage and measured voltage are not the same.

Comment: https://www.batteryjunction.com/olight-16340-650mah.html